# Scale round button on hover without scaling button icon

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have round button  with search icon and when it hovered  the round button should scale whereas search icon should be remain as same.

This is what i'm trying to

for the parent "div" in :after class i'm putting "search glypicon" and position that to the middle of "button" and on hover of "button" its scaled using css "transform" property and "search glyphicon" is not affected as it is outside "button".

Issue i'm facing is as the "search glyphicon" is a part of parent "div" of "button" it lies on the top of "button" and hover will not work of position over "search glyphicon".

if there is  any other alternative let me know,

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/ATpx5/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="global-search-form" role="search">
    <button aria-label="Search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#global_search_widget">
        <div class="mask-search"></div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transform effect should take place when hovering over the parent element.

You would therefore change the selector from `.global-search-form button:hover`

to `.global-search-form:hover button`.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4UhFd/)

```
.global-search-form:hover button {
     border-color: #0064d2;
     background: #ffffff;
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
     -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
     -o-transform: scale(1.1);
     transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, i haven't  thought that way :)